# Restrict map() to only run on a list of headers in an array made from a range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, map-function

I want to restrict the map to only those columns of the range that are in the list `headers` which is a subset of `v[0]` so that only the values in the columns of the range listed in `headers` are changed.

```
function test() {
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Elements');  
  var rng = sht.getDataRange();
  var v   = rng.getValues();
  
  var headers = ['Id', 'Label'];
  //headers is a subset of v[0]
  

  //This will work for `all` values of the values
  //values = v.map(x => x.map(y => y==("Networking - 1") ? 1: y));

  values = v.map(x => x.map(y => y== cols.includes(y)==true && y=="Networking - 1" ? 1: y))
  
  var sht2 = ss.getSheetByName('AAA');
  sht2.getRange(1,1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
}
```

Comment: To the person who voted to close this question. The question is clear enough and it is not a duplicate of something similar. Therefore, it shouldn't be closed unless there is a close reason that I might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The first step is to get the column indexes where `headers` appears. To do that, you can apply [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to the first row of your data `v` which is the headers row:

  ```
  v[0].indexOf(headers[0])
  v[0].indexOf(headers[1])
  ```
- The next step is to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get only these columns:

  ```
  v.map(d=>[d[v[0].indexOf(headers[0])],d[v[0].indexOf(headers[1])]]);
  ```

### Solution:

```
function test() {
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Elements');  
  var rng = sht.getDataRange();
  var v   = rng.getValues();
  
  
  var headers = ['Id', 'Label'];
  //headers is a subset of v[0]
  
  v = v.map(d=>[d[v[0].indexOf(headers[0])],d[v[0].indexOf(headers[1])]]); // new code

  //This will work for `all` values of the values
  //values = v.map(x => x.map(y => y==("Networking - 1") ? 1: y));

  values = v.map(x => x.map(y => y== cols.includes(y)==true && y=="Networking - 1" ? 1: y))
  
  var sht2 = ss.getSheetByName('AAA');
  sht2.getRange(1,1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
}
```

Comment: Marios, thank you. But I was hoping there was a way to do this without having to create a  new array, just restricting the map to columns listed in headers

Comment: I am not creating a new array but actually redefine the existing one. I guess the other solution would be to use `sht.getRange('A1:A').getValues()` if column Id for example is in column A and the same for column Label and then merge these two results. But this is less efficient but also you need to hard copy the column positions (A1 notations)  in advance.  @xyz333